# Android Studio - Unable to resolve class L after upgrade

Tags: android, android-studio

I've recently upgraded my tools and build.gradle to version 21 in Android Studio.

My apk now crashes on load and I get the following error:

```
 Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mypackage/MyClass; 
 Link of class 'Lcom/mypackage/MyClass
```

Is anyone experiencing similar issues?

I've tried the following but no success:

Cleaning the project
   Restarting android studio
   Re-importing the project

More log details:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.mypackage.MyClass:    
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mypackage.MyClass" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-
lib/com.mypackage-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4301)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mypackage.MyClass" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-
lib/com.mypackage-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502)
```

Comment: Have you changed your targetSdvVersion in build.gradle of the app ? It is 21 now. Not 'L' here after.

Comment: @balachandarkm yes it is 21

Comment: hmmm.. anymore log comments to get more insight ?

Comment: Have you changed your package names ? Are you sure that correct class path is mentioned for activities in manifest. Check your manifest once.

Comment: @balachandarkm yes i've changed the package names for the sake of this post. I'm sure that its the correct class path. I'm working on this with some other people. They are able to create an working apk. It just seems to be an issue with my machine or tools which I can't pin point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found out that this was an issue relating to multi dexing.

I needed to run a script to generate the names of the files for my main-dex-list

The blog post below has a detailed outline of this: http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/generating-main-dex-list-file.html